# Store/load data via (private) website on server with dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, raspberry-pi

Searching for a number of questions/answers, I could not find a solution for my application:

I wrote a web application (HTML/JavaScript and some PHP) to read and control an apparatus through RS232. Commands and data can be submitted and received through a simple serial connection. I use a dedicated Raspberry Pi Zero as a webserver. (Internet Of Things application)

I can read data, change it and store it again in the apparatus. So far so good.

Now I want the possibility to store this data, preferably on the raspberry (the server). This is quite simple with fopen/fwrite/fclose you might think... Yes but what I want is a button on my webpage, and when I click that button I want a save/load dialog popping up in which I can either choose a filename or make one up (for saving), and then store a string of (human-readable) hex bytes *in a file on the server*. I need a 2nd button ´load´ with which I can load such a string *from a file on the server* and send it to my apparatus. 
I´d like a dedicated directory on the server in which I can navigate, all the rest should be blocked from reading/writing. (In /var/www/html/syx/ or /var/www/html/php/syx/, but both open for discussion)

The string of bytes is either 70 bytes long or (bulk dump save/load)  64*70 bytes long. These are settings of the apparatus that I´d like to save.

I´d like to stay on the page that calls the file-dialog if possible, opening a new page would destroy my variables (so I read). Is a pop-up possible?

Now javascript cannot touch the server, and I did not find a save/load dialog box popup for PHP. Is there a simple solution? I´d rather not use a database like SQL.

2nd best would be client-side storage instead of server-side storage, but that is also pretty hard, so it seems...

Regards
Arjen

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Modal Dialog to open the "pop-up" and AJAX calls to run your PHP code to store your data. Take a look at [W3.CSS Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp). It is simple to use and has a companion W3.JS lib for the AJAX part.

Comment: Good link, I can use that. I found this as well:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237790-php-file-browser/

But smaller code is welcome